# a file writer is not working properly with a do while loop

Tags: java

I am having trouble writing data into the file if I set the constructor inside the loop it compiles but it only writes the last input. If a put the constructor outside the loop there is a problem and I cannot figure out how to solve it. I have been trying by all means but nothing has worked

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        boolean isRegularClient;
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner (System.in);
        int userChoice;
        File myFile = new File ("invoices.txt");
        try {
            FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter (myFile);}
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");}
        do{
            System.out.println ("Welcome to Marco's Candy Shop");
            System.out.println ("Our speciality and our unique product is the famous Mysterious Beans.");
            System.out.println ("How many lbs do you want? (only exact amounts)");
            while (!myScan.hasNextInt()){
                myScan.next();
            }
            int quantityCandy = myScan.nextInt();
            System.out.println ("We are giving 20% off to our regular customers. Are you a regular client?");
            String string1 = myScan.next();
            if ("Yes".equals(string1) || "yes".equals(string1)){
                isRegularClient = true;
            }
            else {
                isRegularClient = false;
            }
            System.out.println ("Please Enter your billing adress");
            String adress = myScan.next();
            System.out.println ("How much is your local tax rate? (enter as percent)");
            while (!myScan.hasNextDouble()){
                myScan.next();
            }
            double taxRate = myScan.nextDouble();
            Client newClient = new Client(adress,isRegularClient,quantityCandy,taxRate);
            final double pricexLB = 0.80;
            final double regularClientDiscount = 0.20;
            double orderPrice = (pricexLB * quantityCandy);
            double orderTax = (orderPrice*taxRate)/100;
            double finalCharge;
            if (isRegularClient){
                finalCharge = (orderPrice-(orderPrice*regularClientDiscount))+orderTax;
            }
            else {
                finalCharge = orderPrice+orderTax;
            }
            System.out.println ("You ordered " + quantityCandy + " lbs of the Mysterious Beans. You have to pay " + finalCharge + "$. This invoice will be sent to " + adress);
            try{
                myWriter.write ("You ordered " + quantityCandy + " lbs of the Mysterious Beans. You have to pay " + finalCharge + "$. This invoice will be sent to " + adress);
                myWriter.close();}
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("An error occurred.");}
            System.out.println ("If you want to make another order please enter 1, otherwise enter any number to exit");
            while (!myScan.hasNextInt()){
            myScan.next();}
            userChoice =  myScan.nextInt();}
        while (1 == userChoice);}
        
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: The do/while loop should be inside the try block. That is where the FileWriter is defined.

Comment: There are a couple of problems.  But the "biggie" is that you can open an output stream in one of two ways: "truncate" (the default), or "append mode".  You want "append mode", e.g. `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);`.  Look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-append-to-file) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening fileWriter in writing mode, it will generally empty the file and add new content. For this you have to open file in append mode.

FileWriter will take two parameters, second one as boolean for append mode, and if you create a filewriter inside try block it only accessible inside that scope, you can't access outside. So you have to move do/while block inside the try/catch too.

```
try {
         FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter (myFile, true);
         do{
            System.out.println ("Welcome to Marco's Candy Shop");
            System.out.println ("Our speciality and our unique product is the famous Mysterious Beans.");
            System.out.println ("How many lbs do you want? (only exact amounts)");
            while (!myScan.hasNextInt()){
                myScan.next();
            }
            int quantityCandy = myScan.nextInt();
            System.out.println ("We are giving 20% off to our regular customers. Are you a regular client?");
            String string1 = myScan.next();
            if ("Yes".equals(string1) || "yes".equals(string1)){
                isRegularClient = true;
            }
            else {
                isRegularClient = false;
            }
            System.out.println ("Please Enter your billing adress");
            String adress = myScan.next();
            System.out.println ("How much is your local tax rate? (enter as percent)");
            while (!myScan.hasNextDouble()){
                myScan.next();
            }
            double taxRate = myScan.nextDouble();
            Client newClient = new Client(adress,isRegularClient,quantityCandy,taxRate);
            final double pricexLB = 0.80;
            final double regularClientDiscount = 0.20;
            double orderPrice = (pricexLB * quantityCandy);
            double orderTax = (orderPrice*taxRate)/100;
            double finalCharge;
            if (isRegularClient){
                finalCharge = (orderPrice-(orderPrice*regularClientDiscount))+orderTax;
            }
            else {
                finalCharge = orderPrice+orderTax;
            }
            System.out.println ("You ordered " + quantityCandy + " lbs of the Mysterious Beans. You have to pay " + finalCharge + "$. This invoice will be sent to " + adress);
            try{
                myWriter.write ("You ordered " + quantityCandy + " lbs of the Mysterious Beans. You have to pay " + finalCharge + "$. This invoice will be sent to " + adress);
                myWriter.close();}
            catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("An error occurred.");}
            System.out.println ("If you want to make another order please enter 1, otherwise enter any number to exit");
            while (!myScan.hasNextInt()){
            myScan.next();}
            userChoice =  myScan.nextInt();}
        while (1 == userChoice);}
} catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
}
```

Refer this [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) for more info.

Comment: You're correct - but you forgot to mention that the OP needs to move his "do" loop as well ;)

Comment: Thank you @paulsm4 i forgot to mention that